# populating a vector by passing a logical test over a list

Tags: r

The list is created by passing the line of code below.

```
ID <- (sapply(strsplit(as.character(ncv$`Identity Number`), ""), as.numeric))
```

The list length:

```
length(ID)
#[1] 3041
```

When I call `head()` on `ID`, the following (see below) expected result occurs.

```
head(ID, 2)

#[[1]]
# [1] 9 4 1 2 0 7 0 6 0 4 0 8 5

#[[2]]
# [1] 9 6 1 0 0 3 5 1 8 3 0 8 3
```

I wish to create a vector populated with the character string, "Female"
every time the 7th element of each list object is less than or equal to 4.
Otherwise it should return "Male" to the vector.

```
   gender <- vector(length = 3041)

    for(i in 1:3041){
      if(ID[[i]][7] <= 4){
        gender[i] <- "Female"
      }else{gender[i] <- "Male"}
    }
```

I get this error:

> Error in if (ID[[i]][7] <= 4) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: If you write `ID[[i]][7] ` in the console when the error occures, you can see what value the error occured on. Or you can just write `i`, to see which list it was

Comment: Hello Ronak I wish to have a vector populated with "Male" and "Female"

Comment: Hello Acarbalcar, the value returned is NA

Comment: Hello Acarbalcar, i returns 3038

Comment: Then that is the issue, you need to handle the `NA` values. R cant compare a number to `NA`, but I can see there already is an answer that provides a solution for it

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the 7th element from every list and compare it's value using `ifelse`

```
ifelse(sapply(ID, '[', 7) <= 4, "female", "male")

#[1] "female" "male"
```

**data**

```
ID <- list(c(9,4,1,2,0,7,0,6,0,4,0,8,5), c(9,6,1,0,0,3,5,1,8,3,0,8,3))
```

---

In case if the values have `NA` we can handle them with an additional condition in `ifelse`

```
seventh_value = sapply(ID, '[', 7)
ifelse(seventh_value > 4 | is.na(seventh_value), "male", "female")

#[1] "male" "male"
```

**data**

```
ID <- list(c(9,4,1,2,0,7,NA,6,0,4,0,8,5), c(9,6,1,0,0,3,5,1,8,3,0,8,3))
```

Comment: Dear @Ronak Thank you very much. Kind regards

Comment: @KhoiSan: A kind regard will be if you can upvote and accept the answer :)